# WPF - how to change XAML and get an immediate view of the affect in VS2010 without compiling/running?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

Is there a way to get an immediate feedback/view of the impact of changing XAML in a WPF application?  i.e. without having to recompile/run?    In VS2010.

In particular I ask this as I'm using the Charting from the WPF Toolkit library, and I'd like to be able to see the change in the UI I make after changing various charting sytles etc, but without having to recompile/run etc (if this is possible)

Comment: Are you asking how to build an application which can read XAML files and generate objects at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS2010 WPF editor works (by default, I think) in a split view, with a live 'designer view' in one half and the XAML text in the other.   In general, the designer part does update itself to follow the XAML without the need to recompile.

With VS2010 you can even arrange to have the designer view on one monitor and the XAML on the other, if that helps.

It would certainly be possible to write a control which didn't update itself properly during XAML editing - perhaps that's what you're seeing.

Can you see the split XAML/designer view when you edit XAML files?  If not, has the splitter bar been pulled completely to the top?

Comment: I"m seeing this - however I think you are probably right - it's seems to be the WPF Toolkit charting component that doesn't show anything in the VS2010 in the 'designer view' (http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/29117)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, not in Visual Studio, no.  The split view in the designer is pretty decent in general, but sometimes it just demands a recompile.

We use [XamlPad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398%28VS.90%29.aspx) for this sort of thing.  [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx) is a lot better for this, too.